# No persister for: Castle.Proxies.<EntityName>Proxy and lazy="true" in NHibernate?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, lazy-loading

I am trying to use lazy loading for a property of one of my entities

The property mapping is something like this:

```
<property name="Foobar" type="AnsiString" column="FOOBAR" lazy="true"/>
```

However when I am tring to save an instance of this entities (using Linq), it throws a DatabaseQueryException with the following inner exception:

`NHibernate.MappingException`: No persister for: Castle.Proxies.FooEntityProxy"

And when I remove the lazy="true" item, the exception doesn't get thrown anymore. What is the problem with using lazy="true" and how to fix this?

Comment: What happened to that property in your session, Has it been loaded or not? Have you modified it in the session?

Comment: @Pedro Assembly Version is 3.1

Comment: is FooEntity subclass, maybe that is the problem....

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a late answer, but I had this same problem earlier.  I was using a custom interceptor to create the proxies, and so I found that the issue was that I hadn't overridden the "GetEntityName" method.  Analyzing the proxy within the GetEntityName method, and returning the proper class name did the trick.

In my case, I had a simple extension method to unproxy my objects, called "UnProxy", so my whole implementation of this method looked like this:

```
public override string GetEntityName(object entity)
{
    if (entity == null)
        return base.GetEntityName(entity);
    return entity.UnProxy().GetType().FullName;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you are using NHibernate 3? I think only this version supports scalar properties lazy loading!

**update**

Not sure if it can help you but try to look here:

[NHibernate lazy loading property - what does build-time bytecode instrumentation mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497179/nhibernate-lazy-loading-property-what-does-build-time-bytecode-instrumentation/1497249#1497249)

or here:

[NHibernate lazy properties behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773871/nhibernate-lazy-properties-behavior/2774569#2774569)

Answer (score 2):

If you mark a property as lazy, it **must be a virtual automatic** property (with no body like `public virtual MyType Baz { get; set; }`). If you attempt to access the underlying field value, instead of going through the property, you will circumvent the lazy loading of the property, and may get unexpected results.

Comment: what is a virtual automatic property?

Comment: A virtual property with no body, e.g. `public virtual SomeType Foo { get; set; }`